# Have subquery in a SELECT return more than one value

Tags: sql-server

I have a subquery that if it returns more than one value, they show in the same column but different line with all the other information would be the same and just the result the result of the subquery would be different.

As it is now, I'm getting an error

> Subquery returned more than 1 value but no operator

The part that matters about my code is:

```
SELECT 
    TABLE1.ID_Cota,
    (SELECT Observacao 
     FROM TABLE2
     INNER JOIN TABLE2A ON TABLE2.ID_TABLE2 = TABLE2A.ID_TABLE2
                        AND TABLE2.ID_COTA  = COTAVINCULADA.ID_COTA_MAE
                        AND TABLE2.ID_OCORRENCIA_CONTEMPLACAO = 335) AS 'OBSERVACAO_COTA_MAE_335',
    FASE335A.OBSERVACAO AS 'OBSERVACAO_COTA_VINCULADA_335'
FROM 
    TABLE1
LEFT JOIN
    ...
```

If all the code is needed, please let me know.

Comment: No. A subquery such as this one must return a single row and a single column.  Please provide a minimal reproducible example of what you are trying to do, so one can understand what you are actually trying to do, and suggest an alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the subquery inside FROM and join it with the other tables

```
SELECT TABLE1.ID_Cota, sub_query.Observacao as  'OBSERVACAO_COTA_MAE_335'
FROM

(SELECT Observacao FROM TABLE2
                   INNER JOIN TABLE2A ON TABLE2.ID_TABLE2 = TABLE2A.ID_TABLE2
                                      AND TABLE2.ID_COTA  = COTAVINCULADA.ID_COTA_MAE
                                      AND TABLE2.ID_OCORRENCIA_CONTEMPLACAO = 335) 
AS sub_query CROSS_JOIN
 TABLE1
 LEFT JOIN..
```